# Rails refusing to acknowledge page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to convince Rails of the existence of a page at `localhost:3000/user_forms/redir` to absolutely no avail. The page appears when I try `rake routes`- as

`user_forms_redir GET    /user_forms/redir(.:format)    user_forms#redir`

It is definitely in the routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "user_forms/redir", to: "user_forms#redir"
```

And there exists a file at `/views/user_forms/redir.html.haml` thus:

```
%h1 Checking Google Auth, please wait...

%p
  If this page continually hangs, please contact
  = mail_to "ex@ex.co.uk"
```

I even have code in my `user_forms_controller.rb` file:

```
  def g_check_auth
    if(@authorization_code.nil?)
      redirect_to user_forms_redir_url
    end
  end

  # GET /user_forms/redir
  def redir
    @user_form = UserForm.new(set_user_form)

    credentials = Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials.new(
      client_id: "xxx",
      client_secret: "xxx",
      scope: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
      "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/",
      ],
      redirect_uri: user_form_url(@user_form))
    @auth_url = credentials.authorization_uri
    redirect_to @auth_url.to_s
  end
```

The program even goes as far as to have `user_forms_redir_url` as a valid path. Yet, upon following that path I get a lovely 404 message.

Comment: Is it perhaps the redirection that causes the problem? What do the logs reveal?

Comment: @RubyRacer Less than nothing; [Here's a link](http://pastebin.com/24bDunTE) should you be interested in it. From start to loading the page the only thing of note is that the it renders a 404 page with no further explanation.

Comment: The controller action redirects the response to `@auth_url`, which means `redir.html.haml` will not be rendered. Looks correct to me.

Comment: @fylooi that would be fine (perfect i  fact) if the controller then loaded the target of the redirection, but instead of loading the index page for user_forms it instead 404s. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: What's the content of `@auth_url.to_s`? That's where it's redirecting to.

Comment: @fylooi `@auth_url.to_s` is a part of the google-drive-ruby gem's OAuth, it authenticates the user with Google then appends the authorization code to the url of the redirect_uri. So in this case it *should* go `any user form page ` -> `auth redirect (rails)` -> `auth url (google)` -> `user form index page`

Comment: Have you debugged and confirmed that the correct url is returned in `@auth_url`? And that url is accessible?

Comment: First of all, you probably want to hide the client_secret on SO. I would check following stuff: 1. is the id/pw correct, 2: does a direct redirection to user_form_url(@user_form) work ? 3. is the @auth_url correct ? 4. Your gem returns an uri with a parameter. Is the parameter permitted in the recieving page ?

Comment: Blimey yeah thanks for the client_secret mention, it's been a long day/night/day. Just ran through those checks- correct URL is returned, accessible if I take it plaintext and try to nav to it, redirects back properly to `http://localhost:3000/user_forms/redir`. ID/PW is correct, yes. As for returning the parameter, it appends it to the end of the page URL and in previous tests it appended it correctly.

Comment: wait, it redirects back to user_forms/redir ? sorry if I understood you wrong, but this would mean that user_froms/redir points back to itself ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo it's only meant to if the client hasn't authorized (i.e. the authorization code is nil). Doesn't actually work, as I've just found out. I found the issue- apparently it needs to be `UserForm.all` and `user_forms_url` instead of `.new` and `user_form_url` . And having discovered this I'm now going to go curl up in a ball and weep.

Comment: it needs to redirect to `g_check_auth` then. But curling up to a ball and weep is always a good strategy ^^